# Set umlauts keyboard shortcuts with gsettings in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gsettings

I want to set umlauts keyboard shortcuts in ubuntu 20.04. I tried the following without success.

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom/']"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom/ name 'ä'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom/ command 'xdotool key adiaeresis'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom/ binding '<Alt>a'
```

If I try the command `xdotool key adiaeresis' in the terminal it results in the desired letter ä. Switchting the command to open a program the keyboard shortcuts works. I think the problem lies in the combination gsettings and xdotools.

Any help is very appreciated!

Thanks,
Johannes!

Comment: Stackoverflow is dedicated to helping solve `if/then/else` programming code (and tools) problems. Your question seems to be about using and configuring *nix tools. Please dlete here and repost to [ubuntu.se] or [su] (only one!). Read their help about how-to-ask and on-topic quesitons. Good luck.